# Does killing the parent actor kill the children too? Seeing some different behaviour

Tags: akka

I was underassumption that, if you kill the parent actor, the children will be killed too, but when I tried something like this given below, I am getting a different behaviour. Could someone please explain?

```
1. Here the actor GrandFather creates Son and Son creates GrandSon. 
2. Grandson sends a message to GandFather, so Grandfather gets the actoRef of the Grandson.
3. Then on receiving a specific message ("crash") from GrandFather, Son throws an exception.
4. Now GrandFather tries to send messages to both Son and GrandSon. Messages to Son goes to Deadletter Queue, whild messsages to GrandSon is received and printed.

 object GrandFather{
   def props()=Props(new GrandFather)
 }
 class GrandFather extends Actor with ActorLogging {
   var child:ActorRef=Actor.noSender
   override def receive: Receive = {
     case x:String if x.equals("Test Grandpa") =>
       println("I am grand father ->" + x)
       child = context.actorOf(Son.props)
       child ! "Test Son"
     case y:String =>
      val grandChild = sender()
      println("I am the grandfather, Got Message from grand child, gonna kill my son")
      child ! "crash"
      child ! "there"
      grandChild ! "Are you Alive?"
       child ! "there"
       grandChild ! "Are you Alive?"
       child ! "there"
       grandChild ! "Are you Alive?"
       child ! "there"
       grandChild ! "Are you Alive?"
       child ! "there"
   }
 }

 object Son{
   def props:Props = Props(new Son)
 }
 class Son extends Actor with ActorLogging {
   var actr:ActorRef = Actor.noSender

   def receive:Receive={
     case y:String if y.equals("crash") => throw new Exception("killed by self")
     case z:String if z.equals("there") => println("I am the son -> " + "still here")
     case x:String => {
       val k = sender()
       println("I am the son -> " + x)
       actr = context.actorOf(GrandSon.props())
       actr ! ("Test GrandChild ", k)
     }
   }
 }

 object GrandSon{
   def props() = Props(new GrandSon)
 }
 class GrandSon extends Actor with ActorLogging {
   def receive:Receive={
     case (x:String, y:ActorRef) => {
       println("I am the grand child -> " + x)
       y ! "go ahead and kill your son, i.e. my father"
     }
     case y:String if y.equals("Are you Alive?") => println("I am Grand Child, grandpa I am still alive")
   }
 }
```

The output of this code:

```
 Testing started at 17:57 ...
 I am grand father ->Test Grandpa
 I am the son -> Test Son
 I am the grand child -> Test GrandChild 
 I am the grandfather, Got Message from grand child, gonna kill my son
 I am Grand Child, grandpa I am still alive
 I am Grand Child, grandpa I am still alive
 I am Grand Child, grandpa I am still alive
 I am Grand Child, grandpa I am still alive
 [WARN] [10/07/2016 17:57:10.818] [test-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://test/user/$a/$a] received dead letter from Actor[akka://test/user/$a#-275386619]: there
 [WARN] [10/07/2016 17:57:10.819] [test-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://test/user/$a/$a] received dead letter from Actor[akka://test/user/$a#-275386619]: there
 [WARN] [10/07/2016 17:57:10.820] [test-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://test/user/$a/$a] received dead letter from Actor[akka://test/user/$a#-275386619]: there
 [WARN] [10/07/2016 17:57:10.821] [test-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://test/user/$a/$a] received dead letter from Actor[akka://test/user/$a#-275386619]: there
 [WARN] [10/07/2016 17:57:10.821] [test-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://test/user/$a/$a] received dead letter from Actor[akka://test/user/$a#-275386619]: there
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per documentation default strategy

```
ActorInitializationException will stop the failing child actor
ActorKilledException will stop the failing child actor
Exception will restart the failing child actor
Other types of Throwable will be escalated to parent actor
```

you are actually not killing the actor but restarting it.

if you want to prove this, override more methods for son actor

like in documentation

```
def preStart(): Unit = ()

def postStop(): Unit = ()

def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]): Unit = {
  context.children foreach { child ⇒
    context.unwatch(child)
    context.stop(child)
  }
  postStop()
}

def postRestart(reason: Throwable): Unit = {
  preStart()
}
```

Comment: As per the documentation, When the supervisor strategy is not defined for an actor(in this case Grand Father) the following exceptions are handled by default: Exception will restart the failing child actor (In this case Son), am I correct?

Comment: yes, per http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/fault-tolerance.html it will restart, but restart the actor doesn't mean restarting children. If you try with PoisonPill it should stop the son and therefore the grandson

import akka.actor.PoisonPill
router ! PoisonPill